# Replacing Unity Time.time with a counter incremented by 100?

Tags: c, unity-game-engine, time

I have come across a situation where if Time.time is called at two different places at different passes in Update() the value will differ
in its increment thus any use of Vector3(0,Time.time,0) will cause
jumps in the results. I have a gameobject that starts a path in
section of code then transitions to another set of code further along
in the script. The gap execution of Time.time in the first call and
the second call is different than the gaps in the loop of the first
call. That is why I am asking about a replacement. Its not about the code. Its about the Time.time variance between the two Time.time usages. I believe there is an execution caused variance.
[image: Path showing corruption]

```
    void Update () {

            synchTime = Time.time;
            // This proc releases gameobject from center into an outward spiralling trajectory till the height orbit path attained,
            // then disables itself releasing the gameobject into the sine wave orbital path.
            if (!reachedElevation)
            {
                transform.Translate(0, Time.deltaTime, 0);
                reachedElevation = true;
                _AgentY = Mathf.Sin(synchTime);//Keeps value started and in synch with usage below

            }else{

            // The trouble is making the 'Y' synch between where the spiral left off and this sine. It has to do with Time.time
            _AgentY = Mathf.Sin(synchTime);

            Debug.Log("Before transform.localPosition.y: " + transform.localPosition.y);
            transform.localPosition = new Vector3(transform.localPosition.x, _AgentY, transform.localPosition.z);
            Debug.Log("After transform.localPosition.y: " + transform.localPosition.y);

            } 
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a local variable at the start of the update call, and set it to Time.time, then you can reference this variable anywhere within the update and it will remain the same.

Comment: I added the 'else', removed the return();, put synchTime = Time.time; as first line in update, removed the synchTime increment, changed to _AgentY = Mathf.Sin(synchTime). The results haven't changed. There is still a jump in the _AgentY variable value.

Comment: I am also running in the editor and not compiled. The profiler shows +75% editor usage. I have been trying to avoid the compile and device push till this point. I am guessing I just have to belay this issue, keep working on my game and then push to see the real performance issues. I was so hoping keep developing long term. This point has to crossed at some point.
I did update the code and added an image.

The jump happens across the 'else' statement. The spiral and the sine paths work great unto themselves.